# Prevent absolutely positioned element on top of div to block div's hover style?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a `div` which has `background-color: blue;`. Now when I hover, it changes to `red`;
I also have an absolutely positioned element, which is (visually) on top of that div, semantically a sibling.

```
<div>
<div>My blue div</div>
<div>My absolutely positioned element, which is actually on top of my blue div</div>
</div>
```

Now when I hover over my absolutely positioned element, my blue div will remain blue, and not take its red hover style, since technically I am not hovering over it directly anymore.

Any way I can prevent this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add some CSS to make your absolute positioned element be ["transparent" for the your pointer(mouse, touch, etc)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) by adding following css. But this will also ignore all other events (click, mouseover etc)

```
.myAbsoluteDiv {
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

if you still want to attach events etc. you can use following more extensive css

```
.blueDiv{
    backgroundColor: blue;
}
.outsideDiv:hover .blueDiv {
   backgroundColor: red;
}
```

Comment: @R.Kohlisch happy I could help! I added a different solution to my answer so you can choose :)